# How to convert array undefined to array string in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this

`const array = [undefined,undefined, undefined]`

and I would like to convert to this

`const array = ["","", ""]`

It's possible ?

I tried this but it's not working

```
 const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const replaceUndefinied= (item) => {
    var str =  JSON.stringify(item, function (key, array) {return (array === undefined) ? setText(array) : array});
    return JSON.parse(str);
 }
```

Comment: `array.map(value => "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fill()`:

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined, undefined];

console.log(arr.fill(""));
```

Or use map: `arr.map(e => "")`

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined, undefined];

console.log(arr.map(e => ""));
```

You can create the array and fill it at the same time: `new Array(3).fill("")`

```js
const arr = new Array(3).fill("");

console.log(arr);
```

And you last part of the code seem to want to keep any value that is not `undefined`, so:

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined, undefined];

console.log(arr.map(e => e === undefined ? "" : e));

const arr2 = [undefined, "Mary" , undefined];

console.log(arr2.map(e => e === undefined ? "" : e));
```

Comment: `e || ""` just in case you have something that's not undefined

Comment: I thought the given condition is that they are all `undefined`

Comment: Yes. However, I just thought it was worth mentioning that. The result is gonna be technically the same.

Comment: @lucas `e || ""` is shorter... but I wonder if the OP wants a `0` or other falsy values to stay... it wasn't specified in the question whether it is always a string

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
let stringMe = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie'];

let arrayLength = stringMe.length;
stringMe.reverse();
let myString = '';
for (;arrayLength >= 1; arrayLength--) {
  let charStorage   = stringMe.pop(); 
  myString = myString + charStorage;
}

console.log(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would keep other values apart from undefined

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined, undefined, 'test'];

console.log(arr.map((arr) => { return (arr === undefined) ? "" : arr }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using replacer, It will work for both array and object

```js
const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({a:1, b: undefined},(_, value) => (value || '')));

console.log(obj)

const array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([1,2,3, undefined],(_, value) => (value || '')));

console.log(array)
```